# Rails 3.1, passing parameters for colection_select from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, form-helpers

I have this collection_select usage in my view:

```
<%= collection_select(:production_year, :id, @car_models, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Year" }, { :disabled => "disabled" } ) %>
```

But it seems, that i'll add much logic for this select box. So i want pass parameters for this collection_select from my controller. How can i do this?

Was trying to pass array with parameters, but got many errors. Pls show correct way for this.

Comment: What logic will you want to add?  Ruby on Rails standards have a lot of power and when you don't use them you can also run into a lot of problems (or code that works but is unmaintainanle except to Ruby experts).

Comment: It will be a chain selects form. And in different cases of params[] of those collection_selects, logic should change prompts, "disabled" and "selected" fields of collection_selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller: `@collection_select_params = [ ... ]`

And in your view: `<%= collection_select(*@collection_select_params) %>`

The `*` prefix will indicate to ruby that this array is to be passed as an args list.